# Escape boolean operators in CloudSearch queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I've been trying to construct a boolean search query, but the value of the field I'm searching on starts with a hypen `-`, which normally is used as the boolean `not` operator. An example might be helpful:

Suppose I had a bunch of movie records and I wanted to search for all movies with the title "-gladiator" in the "drama" genre. Normally my query would look like this:

```
search?bq=(and title:'-gladiator' genre:'drama')
```

The problem is that `-` is interpreted as the `not` operator so this will return to me all of the movies in the drama genre who do not have the title gladiator. I've tried escaping the hyphen with a blackslash and with a url-encoded backslash (%5C), but I get errors from CloudSearch when I do this. So far I can't find any documentation that talks about this.

Does anyone know how to escape boolean operators in boolean search queries?

Relevant documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/booleanoperators.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/booleansearch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you have to escape the operator with two backslashes. Something like this would work:

```
search?bq=(and title:'\\-gladiator' genre:'drama')
```

Also don't forget to url-encode your query string if you're attempting to test this out with curl or something similar.